# Deploy python application

Tags: python, client-server, rich-internet-application

I am developing an application for managers that might be used in a large organisation. The app is improved and extended step by step on a frequent (irregular) basis. The app will have SQL connections to several databases and has a complex GUI.
What would you advise to deploy the app ?
Based on my current (limited) knowledge of apps in lager organisations I prefer a setup where the app runs on a server and the user uses a thin client via the web. I prefer not to use a webbrowser because of (possible)limitations of the user GUI. The user experience should be as if the app was running on his own laptop/pc/tablet(?)

What opensource solution would you advise ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

If possible, make the application run without any installation procedure, and provide it on a network share (e.g. with a fixed UNC path). You didn't specify the client operating system: if it's Windows, create an MSI that sets up something in the start menu that will still make the application launch from the network share.

With that approach, updates will be as simple as replacing the files on the file server - yet it will always run on the client.

Comment: Thansks Martin. You said the app will run on the client